# pandas: grouping over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm learning `pandas`, with a strong SQL background, so I need to rethink many habits and frames of mind. While I think I understand the `groupby()` method, I just can't figure out how to apply it over multiple columns.

Let's say we have this table in a database:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
| id | product_name | category  | subcategory  | price |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
|  1 | product1     | category1 | subcategory1 |  8.41 |
|  2 | product2     | category1 | subcategory1 | 62.74 |
|  3 | product3     | category1 | subcategory2 | 85.84 |
|  4 | product4     | category2 | subcategory2 | 32.71 |
|  5 | product5     | category2 | subcategory1 | 39.62 |
|  6 | product6     | category2 | subcategory1 | 37.43 |
|  7 | product7     | category3 | subcategory2 | 55.01 |
|  8 | product8     | category3 | subcategory1 | 26.91 |
|  9 | product9     | category3 | subcategory3 | 77.13 |
| 10 | product10    | category3 | subcategory3 | 40.79 |
+---+--------------+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

It's very easy to do an aggregate on multiple columns:

```sql
select category, subcategory, avg(price) as avg_price from my_table group by category, subcategory
```

which returns this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| category  | subcategory  | avg_price |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| category1 | subcategory1 |    35.575 |
| category1 | subcategory2 |     85.84 |
| category2 | subcategory1 |    38.525 |
| category2 | subcategory2 |     32.71 |
| category3 | subcategory1 |     26.91 |
| category3 | subcategory2 |     55.01 |
| category3 | subcategory3 |     58.96 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

So, in my obviously incorrect understanding, this would have done the same in pandas:

```py
df['price'].groupby(df[['category', 'subcategory']]).mean()
```

which returns `ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional`, while:

```py
 df['price'].groupby(df['category']).mean()
```

works as expected.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try: `df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory'])['price'].mean()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your `groupby` syntax

```
df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory'])['price'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do -

```
df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory'])['price'].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it!